# Azure Python module to interact with ADLS

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-powershell

Microsoft has powershell module `Az.DataLakeStore` to interact with ADLS.  I am looking for similar thing in python.

Is that such module available if not how could I perform action like `setting permission ADLS path`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to manage Azure Data Lake Store, you can use [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-get-started-cli-2.0) instead of Azure PowerShell.  The Azure CLI is based on python.

Or, you can use [Azure REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datalakeanalytics/datalakestoreaccounts) to manage it.

If you want to use Data Lake Store, this is the Microsoft official Data Lake Store SDK for python: https://github.com/Azure/azure-data-lake-store-python